# Flush left Table of Contents title in revtex4

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, revtex

I am using `revtex4`, and I would like to flush left the title of the table of contents, that I customized to be 'My Title of Table of Contents' in the following example. May you please help me with this?

Thank you

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,aps,superscriptaddress,floats]{revtex4}

\def\tocname{\large{My Title of Table of Contents}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility defining a ragged right variant of section to be used for the ToC:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,aps,superscriptaddress,floats]{revtex4}

\def\tocname{My Title of Table of Contents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\print@toc}
  {\section}
  {\rrsection}
  {}
  {}
\def\rrsection{%
  \@startsection
    {section}%
    {1}%
    {\z@}%
    {0.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {0.5cm}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries\raggedright}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the code above, the change will also apply to the LoF and LoT, which seems to be a good choice for consistency's sake. If this, however, is not desired and the change has to be applied only to the ToC, some other work is needed:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,aps,superscriptaddress,floats]{revtex4}
\def\tocname{My Title of Table of Contents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\oldprint@toc\print@toc
\patchcmd{\oldprint@toc}
  {\section}
  {\rrsection}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\print@toc}
  {\oldprint@toc}
  {}
  {}
\def\rrsection{%
  \@startsection
    {section}%
    {6}%
    {\z@}%
    {0.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {0.5cm}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries\raggedright}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks

- Notice that using my code the font size change for the ToC title is done in the definition of the new sectional unit and not inside `\tocname`.
- `\large` (and similar font switches) are not commands with arguments, so you should use `{\large <text>}` instead of `\large{<text>}`, adding a `\par` before leaving the group, if required.

Comment: The first option works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Michael You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer, if you consider it solved your problem, by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).