# Flush left table of Acronynms

Tags: horizontal-alignment, glossaries, acronyms

This code is building from the [solution found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231793/flush-left-table-of-contents-title-in-revtex4).

How do you go about having the table flush left like this:?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{uri}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}
\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}
\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically erasable programmable
read-only memory}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]

\newglossarystyle{custom_acronyms}
{


    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}
        & ##2
        \tabularnewline}%
}

\begin{document}
No acronyms here.

%\printglossaries
\printglossary[type=acronym,style=custom_acronyms]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glossaries actually uses longtable to generate the glossaries, so what you need to do is tell LaTeX you do not want the default margin setting of the table.
this is done by `\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}`. If this is still not left enough you could push the table even more to the left by using a negative number such as `\setlength{\LTleft}{-5pt}`

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{uri}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}
\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}
\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically erasable programmable
read-only memory}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]

\newglossarystyle{custom_acronyms}
{


    \setglossarystyle{long3col}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}
        & ##2
        \tabularnewline}%
}

\begin{document}
Acronyms here (so that the glo file will be generated): \gls{uri}, \gls{led}, \gls{eeprom}.

%\printglossaries
\setlength\LTleft{-5pt}
\printglossary[type=acronym,style=custom_acronyms]
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]