# Show list of Acronyms that is ONLY mentioned in document

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

From the code's solution that is given [here to flush left the acronyms list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339575/flush-left-table-of-acronynms), how to show ONLY Acronyms in the list, that has been mentioned in the document?  In this case, the list should only contain EEPROM and LED.

I know you can delete that other entry, but without deleting the extra entry, can it be made programmable so as not to show up in the list?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{uri}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}
\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}
\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically erasable programmable
read-only memory}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]

\newglossarystyle{custom_acronyms}
{


    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}
        & ##2
        \tabularnewline}%
}

\begin{document}
Just show \gls{eeprom} and \gls{led}

%\printglossaries
\printglossary[type=acronym,style=custom_acronyms]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Never used the acronyms package, but the [nomencl](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package does this by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing ONLY Acronyms that have been mentioned in the document is the default. However, you tell it to also add all the others with the line:

```
\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]
```

So remove that line.